# 'Turn off hard disk after' doesn't work

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, sleep

I'm running Windows 10, which is installed on an SSD. I have 4 additional hard drives installed in the same desktop computer. In the advanced power options, I have set 'Turn off hard disk after' to 1 Minute, however, even when not using the computer for a couple minutes, it doesn't spin down the drives. I can tell by the noise and by physically putting my hand on the drives to feel the vibration.

I've tried using the built-in Resource Monitor to see if any processes are trying to access these drives - it doesn't seem like it. There's a couple system processes accessing the C:\ drive constantly, but all the other drives are not being accessed. How can I get the drives to also spin down?

Comment: Check this, it is for XP but might still apply: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313300